# .htaccess Condition only apply authentification to staging domain

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm using the following code to block users on my staging subdomain.

```
AuthName "PRIVAT"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/mydomain.com/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

Since I'd like to use the same .htaccess for staging and production I'd like to add an condition if HTTP_HOST = staging.mydomain.com so that only the staging environment is password prodected? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good News:** Yes it is possible :-)

Make use of `mod_setenvif` directive.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^staging\.mydomain\.com$ SECURED

AuthName "PRIVAT"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/mydomain.com/.htpasswd
require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      Allow,Deny
Allow from  all
Deny from env=SECURED
```

Comment: thx anubhava! what would be the correct wrapper to put it in IfModule wrapper? would you wrappe it? What impact has SetEnvIf on performance?<IfModule mod_setenfif.c><IfModule mod_auth_basic.c></IfModule></IfModule>

Comment: Use of `SetEnvIf` is so negligible that you won't be able to notice and yes `<IfModule mod_setenfif.c>` would be right wrapper but worried about wrapping it.